# how to ask Python Xarray.DataArray.max() to find only one max

Tags: python, max, python-xarray

I have a geopotential anomalies netcdf file that I want to find the maximum of the anomalies one by one. However, if I use ds.max(), I get multiple results sometimes. That is because the largest values can occur in multiple locations. Such as region.max():

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (LATITUDE: 1, LONGITUDE: 2)
Coordinates:
  * LONGITUDE  (LONGITUDE) float32 220.5 220.8
  * LATITUDE   (LATITUDE) float32 72.0
    TIME       datetime64[ns] 2021-06-18
Data variables:
    Z_STAR     (LATITUDE, LONGITUDE) float64 196.5 196.5
Attributes:
    history:      PyFerret V7.63 (optimized)  3-Apr-23
    Conventions:  CF-1.6
```

I am wondering if there is a way to tell Xarray to find only one maximum value.

My current solution is to check of the results contain multiple values, if yes, only use the first value. But I am wondering if there are more efficient ways to do it.

Comment: Your current approach sounds good. Only you might not even have to check if there are multiple values but always just take the first one.